# why process_flag trap exit not work here?

Tags: erlang

When I try to use "process_flag" for catching children's error report, The log shows trap_exit doesn't work. The problem make trouble for me for 20 hours.

The following log doesn't contain my trap log which should be shown here, like `" lager:info("loop_1_0,~p,~p",[From,Reason]); %%<---should show this line."`

```
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)20> 05:18:26.048 [info] test_a_1
05:18:26.249 [info] levi_simulate_init_1,false
05:18:26.250 [error] gen_server pid_simulate_reader_user terminated with reason: no match of right hand value 3 in levi_simulate:handle_call/3 line 471
05:18:26.250 [error] CRASH REPORT Process pid_simulate_reader_user with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no match of right hand value 3 in levi_simulate:handle_call/3 line 471 in gen_server:terminate/6 line 747
```

==The following is my example codes:

```
1. `levi_simulate_tests.erl` main content

error_test_a()->
    close_server(?PID_SIMULATE_READER_USER),
    timer:sleep(200),
    lager:info("test_a_1"),
    spawn_trap_exit(fun crash_test_a/0),
    pass.

spawn_trap_exit(Fun)->
        _Pid = spawn(fun()->
                             process_flag(trap_exit,true),
                             Fun(),
                             loop(),
                             lager:info("receive_after loop")
                     end).
loop()->
        receive
            {'EXIT',From,Reason}->
                lager:info("loop_1_0,~p,~p",[From,Reason]); %%<---should show this line.
            X ->
                lager:info("loop_2,~p",[X]),
                loop()
        after 3000 ->
                ok
        end.
crash_test_a()->
        close_server(?PID_SIMULATE_READER_USER),
        timer:sleep(200),
       {ok,Pid} = levi_simulate:start_link(false,?PID_SIMULATE_READER_USER,true,[]),
        Id = 1,
        gen_server:call(Pid,{test_only}),
        ok.
 close_server(Server)->    
        try
            Pid = whereis(Server),
            case is_process_alive(Pid) of
                true ->
                   exit(Pid,shut);
                false ->
                    ok
            end
        catch
            _:_->
                ok
        end.
```

===

```
2. levi_simulate.erl main content
-module(levi_simulate).
-compile([{parse_transform, lager_transform}]).
-behaviour(gen_server).

start_link(Need_link_ui_pid,Server_name,Connection_condition,
           Tag_id_list) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local,Server_name},?MODULE, 
                          [Need_link_ui_pid,Server_name,
                           Connection_condition,Tag_id_list], []).

init([Need_link_ui_pid,Server_name,Connection_condition,Tag_id_list]) ->
    case Need_link_ui_pid of
        true ->
            true = erlang:link(whereis(?PID_UI));
        false ->
            lager:info("levi_simulate_init_1,false"),
            ok
    end,     
    %% A = 2,
    %% A = 3,
    ok = levi_tag:init(Tag_id_list),
    {ok, #state{connection_condition=Connection_condition,
                pid_symbol = Server_name}}.

handle_call(Request, From, State) ->
    A = 2,
    A = 3,    %% <------ create exit here
    {reply,ok,State}.
```

Comment: maybe it is caused by synchronized calling. When it is synchronized calling between both pid (linked together), both will be crashed, no exit messages will be received by the other pid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason could be that when you generate an error in the `handle_call/3` it will cause the `gen_server:call/2` to generate an exception and crash the calling process as well. In which you will never enter the `loop/0` function. And easy way to test this would be to replace the `gen_server` call with

```
catch gen_server:call(Pid,{test_only}),
```

and see what happens.